# Setting a specific cell on the active sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to set the value of a single cell on the active spread sheet. I know that I can uses .setValue to record a value to a single cell range. I want to get the range of a single cell than use .setValue to give it a specific value. I am using the following

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
var testing_range = sheet.getRange("range_BOL_number");

logger.log("Rows: " + testing_range.getHeight() + "  Columns: " +    testing_range.getWidth());

var cell = testing_range.getCell(1, 0);
cell.setValue('999');
```

The problem is that when I try and run it, I get an error that says that the getCell call is out side of the range. The log entry tells me that testing_range is 2 rows by 1 column.  Not sure what I am doing wrong as I copied the getCell code from the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because getCell parameters are not zero based but one-based. you can see that from the example in the official docs. it uses getCell(1,1) to get the first cell from the example range:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

personally i think it should be zero based as the parameters are not really "row" and "column" but a delta.